# If I changing a Javascript native code will it affect the jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to prevent users from inserting javascript commands in the url to prevent them from changing hidden input field values and submitting it to the database.

So if I change some native functions at the end of each page for example.

```
document.getElementById = function(a){ alert('no!') }
```

Will it mess up jQuery from getting ids and classes in its executions?

Comment: You can reference form controls other ways than by using getElementById, and you can send bogus HTTP requests other ways than by submitting a form. Validate at the server as if you have no idea where the request came from.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother doing that as there is no way to prevent what you're trying to prevent. This should instead be handled server-side. And yes, it will.